# How do I format this dropdown menu properly and remove the 'active' underline from the sub-menu items?

Tags: html, css, navigation, dropdown

I'm adding a dropdown menu to an existing menu because I now need a couple of pages underneath a 'Shop' tab. One will be for digital templates, the other for prints/stickers.

I currently have an 'active' underline so that the menu item of a current page is shown but this understandably is now happening on the dropdown menu too (which I would like to disable, so that only the 'Shop' actually has the active underline, not the items within the sub menu).

Also, how do I format the sub menu so there's an even amount of space between the top and bottom of sub-items. Previously the first sub-navigation item was too far below the 'Shop' so that when I tried to hover the menu, it disappeared before I could click it but currently there's no padding above the first item so it's squashed to the 'Shop'.

NB. The #ccc background is there just so I can figure out the spacing of the items.

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="<?php if($currentPage =='work'){echo 'active';}?> pink"><a href="https://kaye.hu/ett/ismakingprettythings">Work</a></li>
<li class="<?php if($currentPage =='services'){echo 'active';}?> mint"><a href="https://kaye.hu/ett/wantstoworkwithyou">Services</a></li>
<li class="<?php if($currentPage =='shop'){echo 'active';}?> pink"><a href="https://kaye.hu/ett/isshopping">Shop</a>
    
    <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Digital Templates</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Prints &amp; Stickers</a></li>
    </ul>
    
</li>
<li class="tlogo"><a href="https://kaye.hu/ett"><img class="one" alt="Get in touch" src="https://helloarchie.co/img/design/2022/logo.gif" height="57" width="120" /></a></li>
<li class="<?php if($currentPage =='about'){echo 'active';}?> mint"><a href="https://kaye.hu/ett/issociallyawkward">Profile</a></li>
<li class="<?php if($currentPage =='blog'){echo 'active';}?> pink"><a href="https://kaye.hu/ett/isoversharing">Blog</a></li>
<li class="<?php if($currentPage =='contact'){echo 'active';}?> mint"><a href="https://kaye.hu/ett/isreadytochat">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.menu > li { 
display: block;
float: left;
font-family: "Grimer", "soleil", sans-serif;
letter-spacing: 0.1em;
font-size: 0.7em;
margin: 0 0 0 30px;
position: relative;
}

ul.menu li a { padding: 7px; }
ul.menu li.pink.active a { padding-bottom: 7px; border-bottom: #ffbbff solid 4px; }
ul.menu li.mint.active a { padding: 7px; border-bottom: #73eac8 solid 4px; }

ul.menu li a { 
color: #1b1b1b; 
text-decoration: none; 
text-transform: uppercase;  }

ul.menu li.pink a:hover { padding-bottom: 7px; border-bottom: #ffbbff solid 4px; }
ul.menu li.mint a:hover { padding: 7px; border-bottom: #73eac8 solid 4px; }

/* Dropdown Menu */

li {
display: block;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

li:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

ul li ul {
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
left: -25px;
background: #ccc;
display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul,
ul li ul:hover {
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
clear: both;
width: 100%;
line-height: 1.5em;
height: 80px;
border-bottom: none;
}
```